# How can I automatically calculate the derivative of an array based on the best group of points?

Tags: python, numpy, automation, derivative, integral

I have a group of points like the one below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.1,8.2,8.3,8.4,8.5,8.5,8.5,8.5])
y = np.linspace(10,20,len(x))

plt.plot(x*0.1,y,'o', label='x')
plt.xlabel('x * 0.1')
plt.ylabel('y')
```

Figure 1

[image]

And I want to calculate the derivative so that it finds the best combination of a group of points that have growth trends in common. In the end, I would like to have a result like this:

```
x_diff = np.diff(x)
y_diff = np.linspace(10.5,19.5,len(x_diff))
plt.plot(x_diff,y_diff, label='diff(x)')
plt.legend()
```

Figure 2

[image]

To get the result above, I used Numpy's diff function and it calculated the derivative point by point. As the data is noiseless, it works perfectly. But in real data with random noise, the diff function would give me a result like this:

```
x_noise = x + np.random.rand(len(x))*0.3
plt.plot(x_noise*0.1,y,'o', label='x + noise')
plt.xlabel('x + noise * 0.1')
plt.ylabel('y')

x_diff = np.diff(x_noise)
y_diff = np.linspace(10.5,19.5,len(x_diff))
plt.plot(x_diff,y_diff, label='diff(x + noise)')
plt.legend()
```

Figure 3

[image]

Would there be any way to obtain the same result as in Figure 2 with the noisy data in Figure 3? In other words, a way to calculate not the derivative point by point, but an algorithm that automatically finds the best group of points whose derivative would be smoothest?

Comment: In general, it's a very broad subject and there are many approaches to the question. Do you know anything about your data or about the noise? For instance, your sample data looks like it came from a piecewise linear function. Is this always true in your case?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No, the actual data I work with is not linear. These are geoscience data, the function itself is an integral and always increases from bottom to top. There are no negative values. They are not necessarily linear but can be approximated by linear functions.

Comment: Well, if it's geoscience data, does it have a resolution? If a change is less than the resolution, noise could be removed. Is the approximation by linear functions good enough for your purpose? If so, the problem can be re-cast to finding good linear approximations. Also, how precisely do you want to calculate the derivative? For example, you can the non-decreasing property and adjust every value that is smaller than the previous. It will increase smoothness at the expense of accuracy

Comment: Also, if you know anything about the frequency, you could pass your data through a low pass filter. How fast can your data change, in principle?

Comment: I thought of a more brute-force approach, some algorithm that tried to adjust several lines in the x data so that the derivative was more controlled. The algorithm could try to fit the x data with one straight line, then with two, then three, and so on, until a stabilized error. My question would be how to choose the limits between straight lines automatically because they will not always be equally spaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion in the comments, I came up with this:
It relies on a library called PWLF that fits a piece-wise linear function to the data given the number of segments. It can be installed using `pip install pwlf`

Here's the idea, no neural networks required. Also, I took the liberty of switching `x` and `y` axes as your ordering hurts my brain a little.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pwlf

# data
y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5])
x = np.linspace(10, 20, len(y))

# add noise
y = y + np.random.rand(len(x))*0.3

# options for number of segments
segments_count = list(range(2, 10))

# bookkeeping lists
mse_list = []
breaks_list = []

# initiate PWLF
my_pwlf = pwlf.PiecewiseLinFit(x, y)

# iterate over possible number of segments and calculate piece-wise linear fit
# for each option and store the mean square error vs the data
for i in segments_count:
    print(f"Calculating fit for {i} segments")
    breaks = my_pwlf.fit(i)
    mse = np.square((y - my_pwlf.predict(x))).mean()
    mse_list.append(mse)
    breaks_list.append(breaks)

print("\nDone")

# convert to numpy array
mse_array = np.array(mse_list)

# find the number of segments for which the improvement relative to the
# previous number of segments is largest
mse_ratio = mse_array[:-1]/mse_array[1:]
best_idx = np.argmax(mse_ratio) + 1

# recalculate best fit
breaks = my_pwlf.fit(segments_count[best_idx])

# plot improvement as number of segments increases
plt.figure()
plt.plot(segments_count, mse_array, 'o')
plt.show()

# plot best fit
x_hat = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
y_hat = my_pwlf.predict(x_hat)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(x_hat, y_hat, '-')
plt.show()
```

Essentially, I iterate over a list of possible number of segments. For each, I fit a piecewise linear function. I find the optimal number of segments by finding the number of segments for which the improvement is the largest.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use a neural network with relu activation of a hidden layer with a number of neurons equal to the number of layers you want to find.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.1,8.2,8.3,8.4,8.5,8.5,8.5,8.5])
y = np.linspace(10,20,len(x))

x_diff = np.diff(x)
y_diff = np.linspace(10.5,19.5,len(x_diff))

x = x + np.random.rand(len(x))*0.3

plt.plot(x*0.1,y,'o', label='x')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import sklearn.pipeline as skp
import sklearn.preprocessing as skpp

nreps = 100
best_score = 0

for n in range(nreps):
    regr = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(10,), activation='relu', max_iter=10000, alpha=0, solver='lbfgs')
    pipe = skp.make_pipeline(skpp.StandardScaler(), regr)
    pipe.fit(y.reshape(-1,1),x)
    score = pipe.score(y.reshape(-1,1),x)
    if score > best_score:
        best_pipe  = pipe
        best_score = score
    if score > 1-1e-6:
        break

x_pred = best_pipe.predict(y.reshape(-1,1))
x_pred_diff = np.diff(x_pred)
x_pred_diff[x_pred_diff < 0] = 0

plt.plot(x_pred*0.1,y, color='red')

plt.plot(x_diff,y_diff, label='diff(x)')
plt.plot(x_pred_diff,y_diff, label='diff(x pred)')
plt.legend()
```

The only issue is that it is very easy for the neural network to get stuck in a local minimum, so he suggested trying several networks (in the example, 100 networks) to find the one that finds the best solution. That's what the for loop in the code above is for.

The network receives y as input and x as output. With the network adjusted, simply predict x using y and derive the predicted x. The result is very good.